# Losing output trained model in Kaggle after commit

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, kaggle, pre-trained-model

I am new to kaggle. I have trained model for 8 hours. After training my model, I already saved my trained model. But, I clicked commit button. Now I want to load my trained model in order to do the submission. However, it's gone. Is there a way to get it back???????????

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already committed the model, you *can* get the output files in your current notebook.

Go to :

**Files** --> **Add or upload dataset**

Select the **Kernel output files** tab and filter by *Your work*.

Your previously committed output files (say, saved models) will be imported to current notebook.

Hope this helps!